# Multi-dimensional arrays in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I was kind of a Java-holic. I wanted to learn more about arrays in C. Is there such an array:

```
int test[5][5][5]
```

I want to know how many integer elements it has. I had three questions:

1. I think there are 125 `int` type elements. Is that correct?
2. Is it correct that `test` has 125 `*int` type elements?
3. Is it correct that `test` has 5 `**int` type elements?

Comment: 1 - yes, 2 - no, 3 - nope

Comment: @MarcoA. can you explain ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> firstly, i think there are 125 int type elements.

That's right. It's an array of 5 arrays of 5 arrays of 5 `int`s, which means there's a total of 125 `int`s.

> secondly, is it correct that above 'test' array has 125 *int type elements?

`*int` is not a valid type - presumably you mean `int*`. Either way, the answer is no. There are no pointers here.

> thirdly, is it correct that the 'test' array has 5 **int type elements?

Again, `**int` is probably meant to be `int**`, but the answer is no. No pointers in this declaration.

Presumably you're asking this because you have some idea that "arrays are pointers" or "arrays are just pointers under the hood" - this idea is wrong. When you ask for an `int[5][5][5]`, you get exactly that - a 3-dimensional array consisting of a total of 125 `int` objects.

Answer (score 0):

This array has 125 elements of type `int`, it doesn't contain anything besides these integers.

Comment: you mean that  counting '*int' elements and '**int' elements for that test integer array is just meaningless? since that array does not even contain any of them?

Comment: the array contains 125 integers, it doesn't contain single pointer, therefore yes, counting int* as members of that array is meaningless in the same way as counting char*, float, (int)(*)(void) in this context is

Answer (score 0):

Let consider declaration

```
int test[5][5][5];
```

step by step.

At first consider declaration like

```
int test[5];
```

test has 5 elements of type `int`.

Now consider

```
int test[5][5];
```

It declares an array of 5 elements of the preceding type `int[5]`.  So as each element of the array in turn an array and contains 5 elements then the total number of elements of type int contained in test is equal to 5 * 5 that is 25.

Now let's return to declaration

```
int test[5][5][5];
```

It defines an array elements of which has type `int[5][5]`. Each element contains 25 objects of type `int`. The array has 5 such elements. So in total it contains 5 * 25 objects of type `int` that is 125 such objects.

So array

```
int test[5][5][5];
```

has 5 elements of type `int[5][5]`

array

```
int test[5][5];
```

has 5 elements of type `int[5]`

and array

```
int test[5];
```

has 5 elements of type `int`.

In C++ a multidimensional array is an array elements of which are in turn arrays (not pointers).

Answer (score 0):

Only the first statement is correct. And you also have another guarantee: multi-dimensional arrays in C++ (notice that C and C++ are two different languages) allocate contiguous memory blocks

> [dcl.array] An object of array type contains a **contiguously** allocated
>   non-empty set of N subobjects of type T.

so the following holds:

```
int array[5][5][5];
int array2[125];

std::cout << (sizeof(array) == sizeof(array2)); // Yes
```

Indices are an abstraction over a different access-pattern.

The second is not correct (`int*` is a different type than `int`). And even in memory-space terms it is generally not guaranteed that an array of 125 integer elements will occupy the same space as an array of 125 integer pointers.

Ditto for the third one.

As a sidenote: arrays are often manipulated through pointers and there's an entire topic called "*pointers arithmetic*" which goes hand-in-hand with arrays, not to mention [arrays decaying into pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/1938163) but **arrays are not pointers**.

Comment: In C, array elements are also contiguous, see K&R first ed. as it dates from ancient times.